# AutodiscoverUrl service could not be located error for Office365 account. How should you use for Office 365 account?

Tags: exchangewebservices

```
 _myService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
_myService.AutodiscoverUrl(AdminPerson.Email, validateRedirectionUrlCallback);
```

AdminPerson.Email is an Office 365 account

Answer (score 0):

AutoDiscover needs to be authenticated so you need to pass in the credentials to search with before calling AutodiscoverURL. eg

```
        _myService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user@domain.com", "password");
```